# Password show/hide using Eye/EyeSlash in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement eye/eyeslash in on my Register form in React.

**This is a function that's is responsible for changing visibility type and eye icon changing.**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export const usePasswordToggle = () => {
  const [visible, setVisibility] = useState();

  const Icon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={visible ? "eye-slash" : "eye"} />;

  const InputType = visible ? "text" : "password";

  return [InputType, Icon];
};
```

**I am trying to implement it in component responsible for registering.**

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import { usePasswordToggle } from "./usePasswordToggle";

class Register1 extends React.Component {
  EmailR = createRef();
  UsernameR = createRef();
  PasswordR = createRef();
  PasswordConfirmR = createRef();

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      message: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // alert(this.PasswordR.current.value);
    // alert(this.PasswordConfirmR.current.value);
    if (this.PasswordR.current.value !== this.PasswordConfirmR.current.value) {
      alert("The passwords doesn't match");
      return false; // The form won't submit
    } else {
      alert("The passwords do match");
      return true; // The form will submit
    }
  };

  onCreateAccount = () => {
    let loginInfo = {
      Username: this.UsernameR.current.value,
      Email: this.EmailR.current.value,
      Password: this.PasswordR.current.value,
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/authenticate/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(loginInfo),
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          this.setState({
            message:
              "New Account is Created Successfully. Check your email to verify Account.",
          });
        }
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="FormDescription">
          {" "}
          Please enter Account details for registration
        </h2>
        <div className="Form">
          <p>
            <label>
              Email: <input type="text" ref={this.EmailR} />
            </label>
          </p>

          <p>
            <label>
              Username: <input type="text" ref={this.UsernameR} />
            </label>
          </p>

          <div>
            <label>
              Password:{" "}
              <input type={usePasswordToggle.InputType} ref={this.PasswordR} />
            </label>
            <span className="password-toogle-icon">
              {usePasswordToggle.Icon}
            </span>
          </div>

          <p>
            <label>
              ReenterPassword:{" "}
              <input type="password" ref={this.PasswordConfirmR} />{" "}
            </label>
          </p>

          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Create </button>

          <p>{this.state.message}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Register1;
```

My password is always visible, and eye icon is even not visible on the form (it should be inside my input field, but it is not).

Focus on this code snippet:

```
<div>
  <label>
    Password: <input type={usePasswordToggle.InputType} ref={this.PasswordR} />
  </label>
  <span className="password-toogle-icon">{usePasswordToggle.Icon}</span>
</div>
```

Any suggestion what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, add a default value to your useState, either true or false depending on which icon you want to render first.

Then, you should add a onClick method to your icon which will toggle the visibility state. You're setting the icon based on visible value, but you never toggle the value.

```
onClick={() => setVisibility(!visible)}
```

**UPDATE**

You also need to execute your Hook inside your main component (because yes, you wrote what React call a Hook), like so :

```
const [inputType, icon] = usePasswordToggle();
```

But doing so, you'll get an error from React that say you cannot use a Hook within a class component due to how they work.

Basically you need to change your Register1 component to be a functional component, and not a class anymore. Look here for a quick overview on how to : https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Where exactly should I put this:

onClick={() => setVisibility(!visible)} ??

Comment: In the FontAwesomeIcon component like this 

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={visible ? "eye-slash" : "eye"} onClick={() => setVisibility(!visible)} />;

Comment: Eye is still not visible. I added const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(true), and suggested code. Nothing changed. Maybe it is the problem the way I am reading {usePasswordToggle.InputType} and {usePasswordToggle.Icon} in Register1 from usePasswordToggle?

Comment: Might be, try to log the content of both values to check everything is fine

Comment: It is undefined. Could you please check the way I am reading the values, is it correct. I am new to React, so I don't have so much experience to analyze the code. Thank you for understanding! :)

Comment: Try to do log usePasswordToggle(), as you are exporting a function if you do not execute it you won't recover the value. To keep it readable you can do : 

const [inputType, icon] = usePasswordToggle();

Comment: If I put const `[inputType, icon] = usePasswordToggle();` inside Register1 I am getting error: `; expected`, and if put outside I am getting error:`react.development.js:1465 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app`

Comment: You need to refactor your component Register1 to be a functional component, it'll work the same, exact it's gonna be shorter, and you'll be able to use your usePasswordToggle within it. Look at the react documentation for a functional component

Comment: I have refactored code. I now have a problem with this:      `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={visible ? {faEyeSlash} : {faEye}} onClick={() => setVisibility(!visible)} />`, it is like cannot read visible from `const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(true);` or maybe it is problem because I have {} inside {}. Full code available here https://codeshare.io/2p13kV

Comment: If I try just `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEyeSlash} onClick={() => setVisibility(!visible)} />` It will work, but I am not switching icon  based onClick event.

Comment: Yup, remove the parenthesis like so : 

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={visible ? faEyeSlash : faEye} onClick={() => setVisibility(!visible)} />

Comment: That's worked. Thank you so much! Do you have any idea how to set up password visible only if I hold eye icon and to hide when I release eye icon?

Comment: No sorry, no idea for that, don't think there's anything out of the box, you'll probably have to do something custom for it. Glad it worked for you, well done ! Don't forget to tag the answer so the question is closed, have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Change this

> const [visible, setVisibility] = useState();

to this

> const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

as the official documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, convert your Register1 component from a class component to a functional component and use the usePasswordToggle hook within it. This ensures compatibility with custom hooks in React.

If you want to keep your class component use this code .
Here is a quick fix .

```js
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import { usePasswordToggle } from "./usePasswordToggle";

class Register1 extends Component {
  EmailR = createRef();
  UsernameR = createRef();
  PasswordR = createRef();
  PasswordConfirmR = createRef();

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: "",
      passwordInputType: "password", // Set default input type
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    if (this.PasswordR.current.value !== this.PasswordConfirmR.current.value) {
      alert("The passwords don't match");
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      alert("The passwords do match");
    }
  };

  togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      passwordInputType: prevState.passwordInputType === "password" ? "text" : "password",
    }));
  };

  onCreateAccount = () => {
    // Your onCreateAccount logic here
  };

  render() {
    const Icon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={this.state.passwordInputType === "password" ? "eye" : "eye-slash"} />;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="FormDescription">
          {" "}
          Please enter Account details for registration
        </h2>
        <div className="Form">
          <p>
            <label>
              Email: <input type="text" ref={this.EmailR} />
            </label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>
              Username: <input type="text" ref={this.UsernameR} />
            </label>
          </p>
          <div>
            <label>
              Password:{" "}
              <input type={this.state.passwordInputType} ref={this.PasswordR} />
            </label>
            <span className="password-toogle-icon" onClick={this.togglePasswordVisibility}>
              {Icon}
            </span>
          </div>
          <p>
            <label>
              ReenterPassword:{" "}
              <input type="password" ref={this.PasswordConfirmR} />{" "}
            </label>
          </p>
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Create </button>
          <p>{this.state.message}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Register1;
```